# Implement a small library

Tags: c

Given the following code implement a small library to make it possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "object.h"

int main() {
    obj_instance *oi1;
    obj_instance *oi2;
    
    object_init();
    
    oi1 = Object.New();
    oi2 = Object.New();

    Object.Set(oi1, 5);
    Object.Set(oi2, 3);
    
    printf("valor de oi1: %d\n", Object.Get(oi1));
    printf("valor de oi2: %d\n", Object.Get(oi2));

    printf("oi1 y oi2 ");
    if(!Object.Equals(oi1, oi2))
        printf("NO ");
    printf("son iguales.\n");

    Object.Set(oi2, 5);
    
    printf("valor de oi1: %d\n", Object.Get(oi1));
    printf("valor de oi2: %d\n", Object.Get(oi2));
    
    printf("oi1 y oi2 ");
    if(!Object.Equals(oi1, oi2))
        printf("NO ");
    printf("son iguales.\n");
   
    Object.Free(oi1);
    puts("oi1 liberado.");
    
    Object.Free(oi2);
    puts("oi2 liberado.");
}
```

**Restrictions:**

The data of the type objects obj_instance can only be accessed through the functions of the Object.Function library. Can not acquire memory using obj_instance as argument to malloc. In other words, the following code, should fail:

```
obj_instance *un_objeto = malloc(sizeof(obj_instance));
```

How to encapsulate the data in C?

Comment: You don't show `object.h` which is essential for us to understand your code. What is `Object`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I wonder in what way knowing the internals of this "class" can help.

Comment: Because C don't have classes, only `struct` & `union`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: same question. In what way knowing if you have a struct or union can help ?

Comment: What you are asking is not really a matter of encapsulation. The malloc trick would still be possible on a C++ object with private members.

Comment: Not I have object.h I must create it is an exercise

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message and the line referred by it. Be sure to tell about your compiler & version & compilation flags. Of course you cannot code `malloc(obj_instance)` if `obj_instance` is some `typedef`

Comment: This member call style of OOP is usually a bad idea. It wastes memory and prevents inlining. When C++ does `obj.memfunc()`, it's equivalent to `obj_struct::memfunc(this)` so if you want to emulate that, the `obj.memfunc()`  should be `obj_struct__memfunc(&obj)` instead . If the method should be late-bound, then the member call is legit ( though you might want  a vtable if you have more than a few of such late-bound methods)

Comment: Why are students so stupid to the point of asking on a forum to have their homework done at their place?

Answer (score 3):

(We don't know `object.h` so we cannot really help)

In general, in C you encapsulate by having *conventions* (and you cannot avoid them, or even ask the compiler to enforce them). A header file would often contain all the definitions of the `struct` & `union` you want to manipulate (*including* their fields). You may add the *convention* of not using these fields (e.g. by calling instead on some `static inline` functions defined in the header). At least you'll document these conventions thru comments (and a bad programmer has the ability to break them, since the compiler won't enforce all these conventions).

A typical example would be the `FILE` type of `<stdio.h>`. It is generally `typedef`-ed as some `struct _IO_FILE` (that name is not important, and free to the implementation; names starting with `_` are implementation reserved) which often would be defined into some deeply included internal header (such as `/usr/include/bits/stdio.h` ...)

Sometimes one can use opaque types. For example, you would `typedef struct object_st Object;` in the header file and only *define* that `struct object_st` in some library (not in the public header), and systematically use `Object*` (i.e. [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)) in every public function. But then you cannot define any `static inline` function operating on it (which could mean a performance loss). With opaque pointers all your functions (which cannot be `inline`) would have `Object*` arguments or results (or public aggregate types with `Object*` fields or elements).
You could look into [GTK](http://gtk.org/) for a real-life example, and read about [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html) (see also the [entire GObject documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) and the [GObject wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject)).

Notice that C is not an object oriented language. You can however (as shown by GTK or Linux kernel code; and both are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) so you can glance into their source code) have *conventions* (sometimes helped by macros) for some object oriented coding style, which remains a *convention* that bad programmers could break.

Without knowledge about your `object.h` we cannot give a much better answer. We don't know what `Object` is, and we need to understand that.

---

If this is a homework (which we won't do for you) and you are asked to *write* the `object.h` header, you can make some deductions:

- `Object` should be some global variable or some macro
- it is an aggregate type (a.k.a. a [compound data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type), that is a `struct` or a `union`) because you use the `.` field extracting notation on it.
- Can the type of `Object` be a `union`? Probably not. Then why?
- so `Object` is some `struct`. what can you tell about it fields? Perhaps some of them might be [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).
- read also about the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Read carefully [its documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html).
  etc...

Comment: Can you give a small example please

Comment: I gave it as `FILE` from `stdio.h`

Comment: As written in the comments, this is a bad idea. And there are other approaches for virtual "methods" like vtables which might be more appropriate. Without exact knowledge about the assignment and its background, it is not a good idea to recommend one way or the other.

Comment: C does not have methods.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's why I used the quotation marks. C does not **support** _methods_. But you can implement the semantics of "methods" very well (as you propose). (I'm really not sure if that answer should be DVed or not. Removed the DV again, as it is ok - in dubio pro reo, but I think the question is too broad for SO)

Comment: "Without knowledge about yourobject.h we cannot give a much better answer" I have to implement object.h is an exercise

Comment: If your exercise is to write `object.h` such that the question code would work, I strongly suggest to read about `GObject` which should be very inspirational (but probably more complex that what your teacher wants). But don't expect us to do your homework.

Comment: if so what is GObject?

Comment: I gave a link in my answer!!! Can't you at least follow it??? I even added another link.... But also GIYF and STFW. And GTK is free software, so study its source code.

Comment: excuse me, I want to do it function pointer inside a typedef struct

Comment: Can you give me any idea please

Comment: I gave some hints. I actually have the feeling to have given too much of them. You are the one learning C. So **you should do your homework** (and that includes reading a lot more before starting to code).